# How to update table in Athena

Tags: sql, amazon-s3, relational-database, amazon-athena

I am creating a table 'A' from another table 'B' in Athena using create sql query. However, Table 'B' is updated with new rows every hour. I want to know how can I update the table A data without dropping table A and creating it again.

I tried dropping table and creating it again, but that seems to create performance issue as every time a new table is getting created. I want to insert only new rows in table A whichever are added in Table B

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Amazon Athena is a **query engine**, not a database.

When a query runs on a table, Athena uses the `location` of a table to determine where the data is stored in an Amazon S3 bucket. It then reads *all* files in that location (including sub-directories) and runs the query on that data.

Therefore, the easiest way to **add data to Amazon Athena tables** is to create additional files in that location in Amazon S3. The next time Athena runs a query, those files will be included as part of the referenced table. Even running the [`INSERT INTO` command](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/insert-into.html) creates new files in that location. (*"Each INSERT operation creates a new file, rather than appending to an existing file."*)

If you wish to copy data from Table-B to Table-A, and you know a way to identify which rows to add (eg there is a column with a timestamp), you could use something like:

```sql
INSERT INTO table_a
SELECT * FROM table_b
WHERE timestamp_field > (SELECT MAX(timestamp_field FROM table_a))
```

Comment: Hey John, is there any way to add timestamp to each row while creating a table in Athena

Comment: No, but there is a hidden `$path` field that can show which source file is providing the value. If the filename is formatted like a date, you could use it to identify the insertion date of the data. See: [Find the source file for an Athena table row](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/find-s3-source-file-athena-table-row/)

Comment: How is the data being added to your Table-B?

Comment: Hi @John, Data is being automatically added in table B using sql query only fetching from parquet format. Thanks a lot for your help. I successfully solved the issue